# How do I extract the username and password out of a URL in a servlet filter?

Tags: servlets, basic-authentication, servlet-filters

I've created a `BasicAuthFilter` and it has this signature:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request,
                     ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException
```

This is working if someone calls the filter with an Authorization header set the right way.  But, if someone on chrome or firefox visits the url like this:

```
http://username:password@localhost:8888
```

The browsers are not populating the Authorization header with that information (which surprised me).  I looked at the information sent by chrome and the username and password are in the request URL but nowhere else.

I can't figure out how to extract that information from the URL.  I've tried a lot of getters on the `HttpServletRequest`, but haven't found anything that gives me the username and password.

NOTE: Yes, I know this is insecure, it's just really convenient to use when you're trying to test your system.

Comment: You *could* parse the URL string manually...

Comment: What happens if you do String url = request.getRequestURI(); and just parse it manually?

Comment: @JanVladimirMostert it contains the path after my host.

Comment: @MonadNewb I'd love to do that, but I'm not sure how to get the full URL.  I've done some research on the matter, but whenever I try the url doesn't have the username/password in it.

Comment: I'm confused. Your question is about extracting the username and password out of a URL, but now you say the URL doesn't have the username and password. You seem to be saying two conflicting things here. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @MonadNewb The filter is receiving a request from the browser.  I don't have a `URL` object, I have a `ServletRequest`.  I'm asking how to get the username and password from the parameters in that signature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My coworker found [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=123150) that implies this isn't possible in modern browsers.  They refuse to send the username:password part of a url over the wire for security reasons.

Comment: which means that you should extract it from the `Authorization` header like I suggested. The fact that you don't receive the header is weird - I would first try to use port 8080 and if that doesn't work, try on a remote machine (not localhost) in order to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 5):

```
    URL url = new URL(custom_url);
    String userInfo = url.getUserInfo();

    String[] userInfoArray = userInfo.split(":");
    System.out.println("username"+userInfoArray[0]);
    System.out.println("password"+userInfoArray[1]);
```

Answer (score -2):

I'll add something to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42359465/1102310)

If the password contains the character `:`, you must specify a limit on your split.

So:

```
String[] userInfoArray = userInfo.split(":");
```

Becomes:

```
String[] userInfoArray = userInfo.split(":", 2);
```

`2` means the pattern `:` is applied only one time (so the resulting length array is at maximum 2)

Answer (score -2):

For passwords with '@', e.g. `"http://user:p@ssw0rd@private.uri.org/some/service"`:

```
    final String authority = uri.getAuthority();

    if (authority != null) {
        final String[] userInfo = authority.split(":", 2);

        if (userInfo.length > 1) {
            this.username = userInfo[0];
            int passDelim = userInfo[1].lastIndexOf('@');

            if (passDelim != -1) {
                this.password = userInfo[1].substring(0, passDelim);
            }
        }
    }
```

Note that in this case trying to use `getUserInfo()` won't help since `userInfo` of the `URI` is `null`.