# How to get username and password from request URL with Spring Boot?

Tags: java, soap, spring-security

I have a webservice (SOAP) that requires basic authentication. I would enable clients to make requests to `http://user:password@server/service`.

As far as I could see, I need to create a new `AuthenticationFilter`. I started by looking at [`BasicAuthenticationFilter`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/master/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/www/BasicAuthenticationFilter.java) and tried to aquire the username and password from the URL by debugging. However, I'm only able to get the `http`, `server` and `service` parts of the URL, not the `user:password`.

I'm using SoapUI for sending testmessages to an URL as described above. I started with Postman, but Postman is smart and converts the username:password part to a basic authentication header. That is not what I want (and I couldn't find the checkbox to change the configuration :)).

How can I get the `user:password` from the URL?

Comment: Why do you need a new `AuthenticationFilter`? For basic authentication you should use the built-in `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. SoapUI supports basic authentication, so there is no need to put user and password in the URL.

Comment: @dur You're right, however my specific client resides in a "protected environment" and needs the basic authentication header to get through a proxy (or something, this particular client is outside my control). This blocks the default header for my endpoint.

Comment: Did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409375/how-do-i-extract-the-username-and-password-out-of-a-url-in-a-servlet-filter?

Comment: I did not, thanks for pointing it out. I did read https://serverfault.com/a/371918/63384 which seems similar.